# AngularJS: Using $scope/$rootScope inside of Service and Factory -- bad or normal practice

Tags: angularjs

I believe this is really not good practice to do such as thing:

```
// factory
... // some logic
$rootScope.$broadcast('SEND_USER');

// controller
$scope.$on('SEND_USER', function() { ... } );
```

because this obviously points out on the wrong logic of the current Factory. But I would like to understand how really it is bad. Could anyone please explain how it decreases the performance and how it complicates $digest loops?

---EDIT---
Let me ask in general:
 Using scope inside of Service and Factory -- bad or normal practice?

Comment: Scope events have nothing to do with digest cycles. This isn't a 'good practice' for design reasons in the first place.

Comment: @estus - Can you elaborate or maybe even point to some documentation stating this isn't a good practice so we could all learn??

Comment: @estus please check this plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/9REy6i0MdO708DHIKrQo?p=preview each `$broadcast` triggers `$digest`, I personally prefer to avoid the broadcast event and instead I use services for correct behaviour and the reason for that is that I find broadcast hard to maintain and read in big projects

Comment: @haakon319 The manual won't say anything about it because it isn't intended to teach best practices. This question deserves a complete answer. But, in a nutshell, it acts as global event bus on root scope, there are not so many good use cases for it. And on child scopes it assumes some hierarchy between controllers, directives and services are better alternatives for this kind of interaction.

Comment: @maurycy It is $interval that triggers a digest, not $broadcast. But you're right about the rest.

Comment: @maurycy I totally agree with you. For me, I see $scope/$rootScope/scope (from directive) only in Controllers and DIrectives -- layers between View (html) and Controller. Scopes should NOT be in Services and Factories., therefore $broadcast, $emit -- only for communication between **Directive** and **Controller**, and **Parent Controller** and **Child Controller**. Factories and Services should return callbacks or promises or objects, but don't insert them in scope.

Comment: Guys, I updated my question: "Using scope inside of Service and Factory -- bad or normal practice?"

Comment: @estus - Thanks for the clarification, I appreciate it :)

Comment: @Novitoll In general this is a bad practice. And a good one is to make a controller and a service communicate directly. More specific example would help.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, thanks guys for comments. So I asked several developers who have a good understanding of AngularJS, I asked the [AngularJS chat room](http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=angularjs&uio=d4), I even posted [Github issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/14473) in AngularJS repo, but they closed it as it is neither bug nor feature (I expected some help from there though).

[image]

### So here is my conclusion:

Decisions on whether to use $rootScope inside of Services / Factories were 50/50, and I dislike such as "not tough discipline" in JS, but it is JS, not Java or Python :)

And my side is on "**Do not use scopes inside of Services/Factories** ".

Here how I see boundaries of scopes:

1) This is a good example for me, the scope is only for interactions between View and Controller:
[image: good example]

2) This is when you have scopes ($scope, $rootScope) inside of your Services
[image: bad example]

And the issue is not only about encapsulation, memory leak etc. It is about the design of you application, so any newcomer to your project can easily understand the surface of your architecture. Also think of the case when you use "Controller as", how you would treat $scope then :)

So I would use scopes and their $broadcast, $emit functions only for:
- Directive <-> Controllers
- Controller <-> Controller

And I would use in Services only functions returning object, promise, callbacks etc. I would even avoid the case when you store some data inside of Service/Factory.